# Nokogiri pattern restriction

Tags: ruby, xml, xsd, nokogiri

Is this supposed to work?

When i use

```
 <xs:pattern value="(!red|green|blue)"/>
```

everything is fine, but using:

```
<xs:pattern value="(?!red|green|blue)"/>
```

(notice the added "?")

**EDIT: found this in another SO question, it doesnt work either**:

```
^((?!red|green|blue)|((red|green|blue).+)).*$
```

Both causes:

```
/home/asdf/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@tretti_order/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/schema.rb:37:in `from_document': Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}pattern': The value '(?!red|green|blue' of the facet 'pattern' is not a valid regular expression. (Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError)
    from /home/asdf/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@tretti_order/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/schema.rb:37:in `new'
    from /home/asdf/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@tretti_order/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/schema.rb:8:in `Schema'
    from xml_validate.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

**Context:**

```
    <xs:simpleType name="attributeIdType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>Attribute Id Type.</xs:appinfo>
      <xs:documentation source="http://www.web3d.org/x3d/specifications/ISO-IEC-19775-1.2-X3D-AbstractSpecification/Part01/fieldsDef.html#SFDouble"/>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
      <xs:pattern value="(?!red|green|blue)"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: What's the semantics of this `?`?

Comment: I want to use it like this: ((ABC_PRODUCT_)(TITLE|DESCRIPTION|RELEASE_DATE|SPECIFICATION_SHEET_URL|THUMBNAIL|FRONT_IMAGE|BACK_IMAGE|BRAND_IMAGE|CAMPAIGN_IMAGE|BRAND_SPECIFICATION_URL))|((?!ABC_PRODUCT_)(.*)) The purpose is to make sure that if a string starts with "ABC_PRODUCT_" it only ends with a certain string

Comment: That's a potential context-free regexp, I'm not sure xs (or whatever the query language is) supports that.

Comment: @Tass Thanks for the answer! I don't quite understand that, what should I google? :)

Comment: Ok, gotcha, bad magic! :) It is apparently something generated by .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have with `(?!foo)` is called a ["zero-width negative lookahead assertion"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html); it says "Make sure that, standing at this spot and looking forward, you *cannot* match this pattern."

According to [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) XML Schema's `pattern` does not support lookarounds of any sort (positive or negative, forward or backward).

However, since you say, *"The purpose is to make sure that if a string starts with `ABC_PRODUCT_` it only ends with a certain string."* you don't need a lookaround. You can simply do this:

```
pattern="(foo|bar_(jim|jam)"
```

This will match "foo", "bar_jim" and "bar_jam", but not "bar_zzz".